# Clients not hitting io.on('connection') when connecting to website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

The server is running fine, and It's hitting the `MongodDB` callback just fine, but It's not hitting `io.on('connection')` callback. No errors are showing up so I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
var express = require('express');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');

var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

//Create the AlchemyAPI object
var AlchemyAPI = require('./alchemyapi');
var alchemyapi = new AlchemyAPI();

// all environments
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; // MONGO DB
var Server = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}




var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://NotPasswordAndNotUsername@serverlocation:12345/db', function(err, doc){
    console.log("Got to callback");
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('Got here');
    });
});
```

Here is my client-side code (index.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onJSClientLoad"></script>
  <script src='http://' + location.hostname + ':3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: refer to socket.io doc. you don't need that cdn link and make a connection from client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening on `server` object not `http`. So try passing it to socket.io instead:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: Hmm, still not hitting.